# Where do Android res Files go in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

From what I have been reading, the platforms folder should never be added to version control. However... the splashscreen/icon documentation on Condova's site states to put the images in the res folder...

So how should I handle this? I wanted to use the merge folder, but that is only for www replacements.

Any ideas would be great. (If I add the platforms folder it causes issues for the next person, even if I try to gitignore files that are created on compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure out what appears to be the best practice currently. I wanted to document this for others as well.

I created a folder for the resources I needed and then wrote a custom hook to copy the files. Here is a great example that I used from http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// This hook copies various resource files 
// from our version control system directories 
// into the appropriate platform specific location
//


// configure all the files to copy.  
// Key of object is the source file, 
// value is the destination location.  
// It's fine to put all platforms' icons 
// and splash screen files here, even if 
// we don't build for all platforms 
// on each developer's box.

var filestocopy = [{
    "config/android/res/drawable/icon.png": 
    "platforms/android/res/drawable/icon.png"
}, {
    "config/android/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png": 
    "platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png"
}, {
    "config/android/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png": 
    "platforms/android/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png"
}, {
    "config/android/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png": 
    "platforms/android/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png"
}, {
    "config/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png": 
    "platforms/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png"
}, {
    "config/android/res/drawable/splash.png": 
    "platforms/android/res/drawable/splash.png"
}, {
    "config/android/res/drawable-hdpi/splash.png": 
    "platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/splash.png"
}, {
    "config/android/res/drawable-ldpi/splash.png": 
    "platforms/android/res/drawable-ldpi/splash.png"
}, {
    "config/android/res/drawable-mdpi/splash.png": 
    "platforms/android/res/drawable-mdpi/splash.png"
}, {
    "config/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/splash.png": 
    "platforms/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/splash.png"
}, {
    "config/ios/Resources/icons/icon-72.png": 
    "platforms/ios/YourAppName/Resources/icons/icon-72.png"
}, {
    "config/ios/Resources/icons/icon.png": 
    "platforms/ios/YourAppName/Resources/icons/icon.png"
}, {
    "config/ios/Resources/icons/icon@2x.png": 
    "platforms/ios/YourAppName/Resources/icons/icon@2x.png"
}, {
    "config/ios/Resources/icons/icon-72@2x.png": 
    "platforms/ios/YourAppName/Resources/icons/icon-72@2x.png"
}, {
    "config/ios/Resources/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png": 
    "platforms/ios/YourAppName/Resources/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png"
}, {
    "config/ios/Resources/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png": 
    "platforms/ios/YourAppName/Resources/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png"
}, {
    "config/ios/Resources/splash/Default~iphone.png":
    "platforms/ios/YourAppName/Resources/splash/Default~iphone.png"
}, {
    "config/ios/Resources/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png": 
     "platforms/ios/YourAppName/Resources/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png"
}, {
    "config/ios/Resources/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png": 
    "platforms/ios/YourAppName/Resources/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
}, ];

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

// no need to configure below
var rootdir = process.argv[2];

filestocopy.forEach(function(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        var val = obj[key];
        var srcfile = path.join(rootdir, key);
        var destfile = path.join(rootdir, val);
        //console.log("copying "+srcfile+" to "+destfile);
        var destdir = path.dirname(destfile);
        if (fs.existsSync(srcfile) &amp;&amp; fs.existsSync(destdir)) {
            fs.createReadStream(srcfile).pipe(
               fs.createWriteStream(destfile));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to note that copying the splash files can be done correctly now through the config.xml, all you need is a local folder at the root of the project for all the icons and splash assets. However, should your app ever need something else copied into the res folder, the currently accepted answer is good way to go.

In my project, at the root of the project folder is another folder called 'res'. Inside, I have an `android` folder and an `ios` folder, to organize all the assets I need.

Then, you just reference the files like so, and cordova will automagically copy them into the correct locations for you.

```
<platform name="android">
      <icon src="res/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
      <icon src="res/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
      <icon src="res/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
      <icon src="res/android/xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />

    <!-- 
    XXHDPI  144×144 drawable-xxhdpi 3   480 DPI 8 to 12 pixels
    XHDPI   96×96   drawable-xhdpi  2   320 DPI 6 to 8 pixels
    HDPI    72×72   drawable-hdpi   1.5 240 DPI 4 to 6 pixels
    MDPI    48×48   drawable-mdpi   1   160 DPI 3 to 4 pixels
     -->
    <splash src="res/android/screen.hdpi.9.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/android/screen.mdpi.9.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/android/screen.xhdpi.9.png" density="xhdpi"/>
</platform>

<platform name="ios">

    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>

    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
</platform>
```